# Оставить самые длинные массивы в массиве

Tags: javascript

Есть массив массивов, допустим:

```
[
  [ '1595862781 1595862783' ],
  [ '1595862781 1595862783', '1595862782 1595862784' ],
  [ '2487562781 2487562783', '2487562782 2487562784' ],
  [ '1595862782 1595862784' ]
]
```

Как оставить в нём самые длинные массивы?

Comment: начать с того, чтобы найти длинну максимального. потом отфильтровать

Comment: если вопрос производительности не интересен, то отсортировать по длине и взять первые с однаковой. хотя это даже сложнее будет

Comment: @teran, понял, спасибо

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
arr = [ ....... ];

let max_length = arr.reduce((res, item) => item.length > res ? item.length : res, -1);
arr = arr.filter(item => item.length === max_length);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function f(arr){
    var len = 0;

    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
        if (arr[i].length > len){
            len = arr[i].length;
        } 
   } 
    var new_arr = [];

    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
        if (arr[i].length == len){
            new_arr.push(arr[i]);
        } 
   } 
    return new_arr;
}
```

Comment: самЫЕ длиннЫЕ, а не один из самых длинных